# Check scenario completion status in specflow in after scenario run in parallel

Tags: specflow

I have seen facets of this question asked elsewhere but there was no solid answer, so I ideally want to have a couple of `[AfterScenario]` bindings run and do some logic based upon the completion state, i.e did it pass/fail, and how did it fail etc.

I know there is a `ScenarioContext.Current.TestError` and some other related classes, but I cannot find docs that indicate if this can be used when tests are run in parallel, so is the above `ScenarioContext` ok to be used in this context or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ScenarioContext.Current in parallel execution, but you can get the current ScenarioContext via Context Injection (see https://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/)

So this works in parallel execution:

```
[Binding]
public class ScenarioStatusBinding
{
  private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

  public ScenarioStatusBinding(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
  {
    _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
  }

  [AfterScenario]
  public void CheckStatusOfScenario()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(_scenarioContext.TestError);
    Console.WriteLine(_scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus);
  }
}
```